# visualize parallel operations

Tags: diagrams, charts

I have a small dataset of operations which I want to display. The operations each have a name, a start time and an end time (in milliseconds).

For example:

> Operation 1: 0 to 3000
>
> Operation 2: 500 to 2600
>
> Operation 3: 1000 to 2900

I want to visualize it in two ways.

In the first visualisation I want to show which operations ran parallel.

Demonstration:

```
Operation 3:        ___________

Operation 2:   ____________

Operation 1: ____________________
```

The second visualization I want to make is basically a chart which visualizes how many operations ran over the whole time. Which would be a chart with a step-after interpolation and these coordinates:

```
(0|1), (500|2), (1000|3), (2600|2), (2900|1), (3000|0)
```

It would be awesome if the two were in one image where the jumps in the second visualization have a vertical line to the beginning or end of an operation to indicate where the jump comes from.

Comment: Maybe look at `pgfgantt`. A Gantt chart seems close o it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer addresses the first visualization you requested.  It introduces three macros `\plotlinescale{}{}`, `\plotline{}{}{}` and `\plotlinelabelwidth{}`.  The first sets the graph value associated with the unit length in the plot-line.  The second passes a label, a start, and a stop value.  The last macro sets a label width.  All graph values must be non-negative.

EDITED with macro `\showplotlinescale{}` which plots a scale line out to its argument value, in increments given by the arguments of `\plotlinescale`

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength\unitdist\newlength\tmpdist
\newcounter{index}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand\plotline[3]{
  \tmpdist=\unitdist\relax%
  \divide\tmpdist by \unitnum\relax%
  \multiply\tmpdist by #2\relax%
  \noindent\makebox[\plotlinelabelsize][l]{#1}: \hspace{\tmpdist}%
  \tmpdist=\unitdist\relax%
  \divide\tmpdist by \unitnum\relax%
  \multiply\tmpdist by \numexpr#3-#2\relax%
  \rule[.2ex]{\tmpdist}{1ex}%
}
\newcommand\plotlinescale[2]{\def\unitnum{#1}\setlength{\unitdist}{#2}}
\newcommand\plotlinelabelwidth[1]{\def\plotlinelabelsize{#1}}
\def\plotlinetick{\rule{.2pt}{2ex}}%
\newcommand\showplotlinescale[1]{%
  \setstackgap{L}{.4\baselineskip}%
  \makebox[\plotlinelabelsize]{}\phantom{: }%
  \setcounter{index}{0}%
  \whiledo{\theindex < \numexpr#1 + 1\relax}{%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\plotlinetick}\hspace{-.5\wd0}\box0\hspace{-.5\wd0}%
    \bclap{\tiny\theindex}%
    \addtocounter{index}{\unitnum}%
    \ifnum\theindex < \numexpr#1 + 1\relax\hspace{\unitdist}\fi%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\plotlinelabelwidth{1.85cm}
\plotlinescale{750}{1.5cm}
\plotline{Operation 1}{0}{3000}\\
\plotline{Operation 2}{500}{2600}\\
\plotline{Operation 3}{1000}{2900}\\
\showplotlinescale{3000}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome thank you. I was able to create the chart with pgfplots.